# How to add title to Container in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I want to add a title or image on the home page of the project, how can I do that? I need help. I want to add an image describing the application above the registration or login form.

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SizeConfig().init(context);
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
        title: _title(),
    ),body: Container(
      height: double.infinity,
      width: double.infinity,
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          _entryField('email', _controllerEmail),
          Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10)),
          _entryField('password', _controllerPassword),
          Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10)),
          _submitButton(),
          _loginOrRegisterButton(),
        ],
      ),
    ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Issue]

Comment: sorry not getting your point, Can you describe what exactly you want and what is wrong with current snippet

Comment: Try the advice from this post:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72255290/how-to-get-titled-container-in-flutter

Comment: @YeasinSheikh I updated it to better explain what I want

Comment: @GilbertKeys not exactly what i want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add items inside `Column` widget,

```dart
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SizeConfig().init(context);
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
        title: _title(),
    ),body: Container(
      height: double.infinity,
      width: double.infinity,
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
         Image.asset("YourImagePath",height: 100,width:200 ,fit: BoxFit.cover,), //here
          _entryField('email', _controllerEmail),
          Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10)),
          _entryField('password', _controllerPassword),
          Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10)),
          _submitButton(),
          _loginOrRegisterButton(),
        ],
      ),
    ),
    );
  }
}
```

Find more about [assets-and-images](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/assets-and-images)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to put an Image widget in your Column, right before the email entryfield. Either an AssetImage or a NetworkImage.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).